# sqlalchemy filter by count column

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have a User query which filters by the amount of orders each user has (ordersCount).

```
User.query.filter('ordersCount>2')
```

If I run it it says: "Unknown column 'ordersCount' in 'where clause'"

From my experience I should be using having on such operations because mysql won't allow it for fields not part of the table but if I run it with having instead of filter I get:

```
(1054, "Unknown column 'ordersCount' in 'having clause'") 'SELECT count(1) AS count_1 \nFROM user \nHAVING ordersCount > 2' ()
```

So how do I filter a count column in sqlalchemy?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

See documentation of [Ordering, Grouping, Limiting, Offset...ing](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/docs/core/tutorial.html#ordering-grouping-limiting-offset-ing). Based on the sample code provided and an assumption that your orders are stored in the `orders` table, your version would look similar to:

```
>>> s = select([orders.c.user_id, func.count(orders.c.id)]).\
...     group_by(orders.c.user_id).having(func.count(orders.c.id) > 2)
```

In this way you will get the `user_id`'s of the users in question. If you want to retrieve `User` objects, just make the `s` about a sub-query and join your `User` query with this sub-query to retrieve the uses in question.