# How can I change my SQLalchemy query to include the current day?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

Currently I have a function which returns the stock ticker with the highest error for the entire data set. What I actually want is to return the stock ticker with the highest error for the current day.

Here is the current function:

```
@main.route('/api/highest/error')
def get_highest_error():
    """
    API which returns the highest stock error for the current day.
    :return: ticker of the stock matching the query.
    """
    sub = db.session.query(db.func.max(Stock.error).label('max_error')).subquery()
    stock = db.session.query(Stock).join(sub, sub.c.max_error == Stock.error).first()
    return stock.ticker
```

Here is what I attempted:

```
todays_stock = db.session.query(db.func.date(Stock.time_stamp) == date.today())
stock = todays_stock.filter(db.func.max(Stock.error))
return stock.ticker
```

Unfortunately this is operating on a BaseQuery which is not what I expected.

I also tried:

```
 stock = Stock.query.filter(db.func.date(Stock.time_stamp) == date.today()).filter(db.func.max(Stock.error)).first()
```

But this generated an error with the message`aggregate functions are not allowed in WHERE`

Comment: Look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6244038/sqlalchemy-filter-by-count-column

Comment: Thanks for the link. Not really seeing how it is relevant? Why would I need to group things? I simply want to filter the results again after checking they are in the current day?

Comment: You can't do a where clause on an aggregate (per your error). You need to use the `having` statement

Comment: I have now gone back to what I know. I have used the max function in python on the object after retrieving them.

`todays = Stock.query.filter(db.func.date(Stock.time_stamp) == date.today()).all()

max_error = max(todays, key=lambda x: x.error)`

Answer (score 0):

The error is pretty self explanatory. You cannot use aggregate functions in the WHERE clause. If you have to eliminate group rows based on aggregates, use HAVING. But that's not what you need: for fetching the row with greatest error order by error in descending order and pick the first row:

```
stock = Stock.query.\
    filter(db.func.date(Stock.time_stamp) == date.today()).\
    order_by(Stock.error.desc().nullslast()).\
    first()
```

Unless you have a ridiculous amount of `Stock` per day, the sorting should be plenty fast. Note that `db.func.date(Stock.time_stamp) == date.today()` is not very index friendly, unless your DB supports functional indexes. Instead you could filter on a half open range:

```
today = date.today()

...
    filter(Stock.time_stamp >= today,
           Stock.time_stamp < today + timedelta(days=1)).\
```